# Couchbase Lite 1.4.4 and .NET 7

Tags: couchbase-lite

I’m upgrading a client’s Xamarin Android app to .NET 7 Android. I’m unfamiliar with Couchbase.Lite and am beginning the learning curve. The app is running an old version of Couchbase.Lite (1.4.4) along with Couchbase.Lite.Storage.SQLCipher (1.4.4) and Couchbase.Lite.SystemSQLite (1.4.4).

It looks like a hefty upgrade path to the latest version of Couchbase.Lite. Is it possible to use these older packages with .NET 7?

Couchbase Lite 1.4.4 seems to basically work with .NET 7 but I'm running into a few issues and wonder if it's caused by an incompatibility with .NET 7.

For example, after saving docs to the database, I try to retrieve them with the following query and nothing is returned.

{[Query: Database=Database[/data/user/0/com.kordata.mobile/files/sandboxtestninyoadmin.cblite2], Limit=2147483647, Skip=0, Descending=False, StartKey=null,EndKey=null, StartKeyDocId=null, EndKeyDocId=null, InclusiveStart=True, InclusiveEnd=True,IndexUpdateMode=Before, AllDocsMode=AllDocs, Keys=, MapOnly=True, GroupLevel=0, Prefetch=False,IncludeDeleted=False, PostFilter=, PrefixMatchLevel=0]}

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm not getting an error when I run the query. It's just not returning any records.